# Mango plant is dropping leaves

Tags: fruit-trees, seedlings, mango

My mango seedling is lately getting brown curly leaves and dropping them, what could be the reason of this, I give it water when the soil is getting dry (aprox every 3-4 days).

The most upper leaves started first and it looks like it is slowly creeping to the lower leaves.

Could it be an illness of anything? Would it be possible to save it still or would it be to late? I also think the plant is not realy growing anymore.

The soil is just potting soil without any special thing added.

[image: Mango]

[image: Leaf]

[image: Dropped leaves]

[image: Underside]

[image: Little spider webs]

[image: Insect]

[image: Closeup insect]

Comment: It might be insects. can you add a picture of the underside of a leaf on the plant?

Comment: I have added them, those black spiclkes are sand grains (because I repotted it some time ago (after the issue shown up)), but I do see very small spider web ish things on the last photo

Comment: I have took a good closeup look on it, and I see a verrrry tiny insect walking

Comment: If the leaf symptoms persist beyond the mites, I might suspect that the mites spread a disease, such as Verticillium or Fusarium, to the tree. Finding out if you have either of those diseases (even if it's outdoors) in your area would be helpful for probable diagnosis.

Comment: The tree has lately not been outside, only when it was summer, right now its way to cold for the plant to survive outside in my country. As far I know no other plants inside have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I see webs on the stems and this makes me think the problem is spider mites.   I suggest an immediate bath in soap and water repeated at least twice at five day intervals.

Fill a sink or bucket with 5 ml dish soap and a liter or more of water.  Dip the plant in, wait a minute for the soap to clog the spiracles of any insects and rinse with clean water.

Comment: I will try this, do you think the plant has a chance of surviving? also how can I prevent those insects to place themselves on my tree, or is this a thing that is inevitable